# What is the name of the add-on that adds "half and mirror mesh" options when pressing 'Q' key?

Tags: add-on, shortcut

I have blender installed at two locations, on one pc, which is at work I have this amazing add-on that adds to the <kbd>Q</kbd> hot key options like, "half and mirror mesh" which I use all the time.  I'm at home and I really want to install that add-on here. but I don't know the name of it.

### update

Here's a screenshot of the add-on
[image: showing add-on menu]

Comment: not with <kbd>Q</kbd> but ? http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.fr/2014/07/addon-auto-mirror.html

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the problem. At home I have quicktools version 0.7. The extra features I was missing were added in version 0.8.  The Github site with the add-on is only at version 0.7. I located version 0.8 hidden deep in the cgcookie site. I tried to install it locally it was failing, I didn't notice because the message was in the window header and flashed too quickly. So, to sum it up. I knew all along the right add-on, but it was failing to install and replace the previous version I had on my machine already.

Comment: And its name is?

Comment: Oh yeah oops.  Edited my answer. It was quicktools.